# How do I make a barebones "Hello World" project in Xcode, starting from empty scratch?

Tags: xcode

I'm learning to create a project in Xcode starting from scratch.  When I looked up how to make a baseline simple Xcode project, I didn't find anything.

How do I make a barebones "Hello World" project in Xcode, starting from empty scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These instructions are for cpp, but can easily be translated to c or c# by changing the main filename and target build type.

In order to get a project started from empty you must add a main file, define a compilation target, and select it.  Details below:

1. First, create a new Project from an "empty" template
2. Next, add a main file.  For example, in cpp you would add  amain.cpp file with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello, World!";
   return 0;
}
```

3. Then you must add a target.  In the help menu search "Add Target", it should open a window.  In the window, select your target.  For a default project one would choose "Command Line Tool" found in the "macOS" category.

[image]

4. After selecting a target time, there will be a form.  Lookup any fields you're unsure of.
5. Once you've added the target, select it for building from the top left corner of xcode
   [image]
6. You should now be able to click the "Play" button to build (or use the help menu search to find "build")